# Core data stack in Swift 3 backward compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I created a new project, including core data into the project. Now when initializing my managed object context, I do it like this:

```
self.managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

And this works fine on iOS 10 devices... but now I need my app to work on iOS 9 as well. So I try to handle the situation as follows:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        self.managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    } else {
        // iOS 9.0 and below - however it was previously handled
        guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Color_Map", withExtension:"momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
        }
        let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        self.managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
        let storeURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("Color_Map.sqlite")
        do {
            try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: nil)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
        }

    }
```

But it ends up always executing the line of code:
     fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")

I'm pretty sure my main bundle name is technically "Color Map", so I've tried modifying the 'forResource' argument in `guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Color_Map", withExtension:"momd")` to that, but still no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

A minor change in the method name should fix this :

Try

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Color_Map", withExtension:"mord")
or
Bundle.main.urlForResource("Color_Map", withExtension:"momd")
```

instead of

```
 Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Color_Map", withExtension:"momd")
```

### UPDATE:

The compilation issue is not related to Swift 3 but the change in the iOS 10 SDK for Core Data classes. Here is a solution to make it work on iOS 10 and making it compatible for lower versions :

```
 var context: NSManagedObjectContext?   

 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    } else {
        // iOS 9.0 and below - however you were previously handling it
        guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Color_Map", withExtension:"momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
        }
        let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
        let storeURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("Color_Map.sqlite")
        do {
            try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: nil)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your suggested code is Swift 2, OP uses Swift 3. How would that fix a runtime problem?

Comment: @MartinR, That was quick one from your end as well as mine. if you would have checked after a few seconds, you will see that I have added both the swift 2 and swift 3 versions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Unless I am mistaken, both suggested line `NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(..)` and `Bundle.main.urlForResource(..)` do *not* compile with Swift 3.

Comment: Yes Martin, you're right. The lines of codes you mentioned do not compile for Swift 3.

Comment: The compilation issue is not because of Swift 3 but changes in Core Data SDK in iOS 10. Please check updated answer.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between your updated answer and the code from the question? That would help future readers to better understand the problem.

Comment: Yes please @Tushar, as the very first line of the older iOS versions `guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Color_Map", withExtension:"momd") else` is the same as mine, and that's the guard that fails for me to begin with.